# The same code behaves differ on localhost and apache server

Tags: django, bash, apache, python-2.7

I have django project like this:

view.py

```
def runKeyGenProcess(request):
message = "User not autentificated!Please either signup or login"
req_user = request.user
openKeyGen = ['openvpn', '--genkey', '--secret', 'key_' + str(req_user)]
openKeyTest = ['openvpn', '--test-crypto', '--secret', 'key_' + str(req_user)]
if request.method == 'POST' and request.user.is_authenticated(): 

    os.chdir('/etc/openvpn')
    try:
        subprocess.Popen(openKeyGen)
        subprocess.Popen(openKeyTest)
    except IndexError:
        print "Server error"

return HttpResponse(message)
```

scrit.py

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.progress-button').progressInitialize();

$('#submitButton').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).progressTimed(3);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/run-key-gen-process/"
            }).done(function(response) {
              $( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
               setTimeout(function(){
               $("#jmessage").addClass("alert alert-success")
               .text( "Key was successfully generated and tested!" );
             }, 4000);
        });
    });
});
```

});

My code behaves very strange. If I run it as python manage.py runserver domainname.com:80, code works well.

Otherwise,if I stop local host (ctrl+C) and then start apache(service apache2 start) it get error:

> Traceback:
>   File "/var/www/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>     132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>   File "/var/www/pulsarvoip/src/pulsarvpn/views/button_handler.py" in runKeyGenProcess
>     38.             subprocess.Popen(openKeyGen)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py" in **init**
>     679.                             errread, errwrite)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py" in _execute_child
>     1259.                 raise child_exception
>   Exception Type: OSError at /run-key-gen-process/
>   Exception Value: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I tried it many times in Firefox and Chrome and in incognito window as well.
What might it be?

UPDATED: changed pach as absolute like this:

.....

```
 req_user = request.user
    openKeyGen = ('cd /etc/openvpn && openvpn --genkey --secret key_' + str(req_user))
    openKeyTest = ('cd /etc/openvpn && openvpn --test-crypto --secret key_' + str(req_user))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            subprocess.Popen(openKeyGen)
            subprocess.Popen(openKeyTest)
....
```

but now both variants have same error (shown above).

***UPDATED2:***  add

> subprocess.Popen(openKeyGen, **sheel=True**)

after this code at last works both on local and apache but generate key in folder only if run local! I wonder,why!?

Comment: Maybe try calling the subprocess with an absolute path and avoid os.chdir? Are those binaries available to the user running apache?

Comment: "Are those binaries available to the user running apache?" sorry, I misunderstand what do you mean?

Comment: The user running the apache process should be able to execute /etc/openvpn/openvpn binary and to write into /etc/openvpn folder, which probably isn't the case. Try writing the key file to a directory where the apache user has write permissions, i.e. change the Popen call so that you write the key to another directory: '/tmp/key_' + str(req_user)

Comment: made /tmp dir, gave 47777 permissions to it but nothing changed: localhost does, apache don't, error the same